# How to say "the day after the day after tomorrow"

Tags: translation

In my language you can just keep adding a particle before "the day after tomorrow" and with every particle it becomes the day after that. I was just wondering whether there is a way to say this in Japanese.

I can think of something like 「明後日の次の日」 but is there some suffix or prefix you can add to something as many times as you need it?

Also, is there a way to say "the day before the day before yesterday" in a similar way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We say (in my region, at least)...

> あさって (明後日) -- the day after tomorrow <sub>(can also be read みょうごにち)</sub>
>   **し**あさって (明々後日) -- two days after tomorrow <sub>(can also be read みょうみょうごにち)</sub>
>   **しし**あさって (明々々後日) -- three days after tomorrow <sub>(can also be read みょうみょうみょうごにち)</sub>
>
> おととい/おとつい (一昨日) -- the day before yesterday <sub>(can also be read いっさくじつ)</sub>
>   **さき**おととい/**さき**おとつい (一昨々日) -- two days before yesterday <sub>(can also be read いっさくさくじつ)</sub>
>   (but not **さきさき**おととい/**さきさき**おとつい...)

Comment: Thanks! It seems that in the first you can just repeat the kanji multiple times for more days but I don't get how you'd say '3 days before yesterday'.

Comment: "3 days before yesterday" は、「[四日前]{よっかまえ}」ですかね・・

Comment: Yeah... Sorry for the dumb question. 有り難う御座います 。 :)

Comment: 「おっととととい」じゃなかったんだ… 